# Unable to send messages to ASB Queue from WSO2 EI : Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am unable to send the message to ASB Queue and getting the following error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender$SenderCreationException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target: testqueue
```

I can see the request in ASB dashboard but the messages are not getting stored.

**Here is the jndi configuration.**

```
connectionfactory.ASBQueueConnectionFactory = amqps://<POLICY_NAME>:<BASE64_ENCODE_POLICY_KEY>@<NAMESPACE>.servicebus.windows.net
queue.QUEUE = testqueue
```

**Axis2.xml configuration**

```
<parameter name="ASBQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">ASBQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>
```

**Message store configuration:**

```
<messageStore xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
              class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore"
              name="JMSASBQueueTest">
   <parameter name="store.jms.destination">mdmaccountqueue</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.failover.message.store.name">JMSASBQueueTest</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.connection.factory">ASBQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

Any suggestions on this to how to move forward. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Yadhu

Comment: Try out this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ESB+as+a+RabbitMQ+Message+Producer